# EGARCH formulation

Tags: garch, modelling

I am a bit confused about the formulation of the EGARCH(1,1) model.
First, we have the error term: $\epsilon_t=\sigma_t*\zeta_t$, where $\zeta_t$ is white noise.

Now the EGARCH(1,1) should be:
$$
log(\sigma_t^2)=w+\alpha_1*log(\sigma_{(t-1)}^2)+g(\zeta_t)  
$$
but instead I always see $g(\epsilon_t)$.
does anyone know why?

Thank you

Comment: If you use latex then it works better if you add the $$ signs ;)

Comment: Yeh thanks. any idea about my question?

Comment: Good point, I will answer

Comment: You need a $\log$ on the lhs of the equation.

Comment: Yes of course, I must have missed it out

Answer (score 2):

Just a quick fix. Looking at the [wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autoregressive_conditional_heteroskedasticity#EGARCH) of EGARCH: $g(\zeta_t)$ (the unit-scale random variable) seems correct - as you say.

Comment: Yes but then everybody writes $g(\epsilon_t)$, not sure why

Comment: Could you post a link to a reference?